# How to get update on Irish passport application

Tags: passports, paperwork, ireland

I am a UK citizen (and resident in the UK) with an Irish parent. I have a UK passport and decided to apply for an Irish passport as well. I made the mistake of sending off my UK passport for the Irish passport application instead of having a certified copy made - as this was well in advance of any planned travel, I thought this would be safe enough… roll on a few months and I have already had to cancel one trip and there is the prospect of having to cancel another in July.

I am finding it nearly impossible to get in touch with the Irish authority for this - the DFA. They don’t provide an email for queries, only a phone number which is always busy and a webchat which is also always busy. I have written to the gov minister in charge of this department, but have had only an acknowledgment of receipt of the email - no further update despite several follow-ups from me.

I have also written a letter of complaint to the relevant body, but that also has not been acknowledged.

I have also written to my local MP to seek their advice, again without any acknowledgment as yet.

What other powers or options do I have?

Comment: Where are you currently living? If in the UK/NI, your MP will not be able to help you with issues related to Ireland. I don't know the irish parliment, but there might be a MP elected to represent citizens abroad, this can be helpful